# Is there a way to group arguments in a record when using Cmdliner?

Tags: ocaml

Let's say I have the following code

```ml
let main a b c d e = Format.eprintf "%B %B %B %B %B@." a b c d e

let cmd =
  let open Cmdliner in
  let a = Arg.(value & flag & info ["a"] ~doc:"a") in
  let b = Arg.(value & flag & info ["b"] ~doc:"b") in
  let c = Arg.(value & flag & info ["c"] ~doc:"c") in
  let d = Arg.(value & flag & info ["d"] ~doc:"d") in
  let e = Arg.(value & flag & info ["e"] ~doc:"e") in

  Term.(const main $ a $ b $ c $ d $ e), Term.(info "test" ~version:"1" ~doc:"abcde" ~exits:default_exits ~man:[])

let () = Cmdliner.Term.(exit @@ eval cmd)
```

If I execute my program with no option I will obtain `false false false false false` and if I use it with `-ade` I will obtain `true false false true true` which is exactly what I wanted.

Now, suppose I made a typo in my `main` function and wrote instead

```ml
(* Notice the d before c *)
let main a b d c e = Format.eprintf "%B %B %B %B %B@." a b c d e
```

If I execute my main program with `-ade` like previously I will obtain `true false true false true` which can be considered wrong.

So, what I wanted to know is if it was possible to gather options in a record to use them with their proper names, something like the following example (which doesn't work) :

```ml
open Cmdliner

type o = {a : bool Term.t;
          b : bool Term.t;
          c : bool Term.t;
          d : bool Term.t;
          e : bool Term.t;}

(* a - e are not booleans but bool Term.t which gives an obvious error *)
let main {a; b; c; d; e} = Format.eprintf "%B %B %B %B %B@." a b c d e

let cmd =
  let a = Arg.(value & flag & info ["a"] ~doc:"a") in
  let b = Arg.(value & flag & info ["b"] ~doc:"b") in
  let c = Arg.(value & flag & info ["c"] ~doc:"c") in
  let d = Arg.(value & flag & info ["d"] ~doc:"d") in
  let e = Arg.(value & flag & info ["e"] ~doc:"e") in

  let o = Term.const {a; b; c; d; e} in
  Term.(const main $ o), Term.(info "test" ~version:"1" ~doc:"abcde" ~exits:default_exits ~man:[])

let () = Cmdliner.Term.(exit @@ eval cmd)
```

This could be useful on big projects and would lighten the number of arguments given to the functions. Maybe there's a way to do it but all the examples I found used the first way of doing. I didn't want to open an issue on the github page so I asked it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with relatively few boilerplate by using labels to emulate a record with `Term.t` fields, for instance:

```ocaml
type arg = {a : bool; b : bool; c : bool; d : bool; e : bool}
                                                                    
let main {a; b; c; d; e} = Format.printf "%B %B %B %B %B@." a b c d e
                                                                    
let cmd =
  let open Cmdliner in              
  let arg ~a ~b ~c ~d ~e =                     
    Term.(const (fun a b c d e -> {a; b; c; d; e}) $ a $ b $ c $ d $ e)
  in                                            
  let a = Arg.(value & flag & info ["a"] ~doc:"a") in
  let b = Arg.(value & flag & info ["b"] ~doc:"b") in
  let c = Arg.(value & flag & info ["c"] ~doc:"c") in
  let d = Arg.(value & flag & info ["d"] ~doc:"d") in
  let e = Arg.(value & flag & info ["e"] ~doc:"e") in                                                                                    
  Term.
    ( const main $ arg ~a ~b ~c ~d ~e
    , info "test" ~version:"1" ~doc:"abcde" ~exits:default_exits ~man:[] )
                                                                                                                                         
let () = Cmdliner.Term.(exit @@ eval cmd)
```

By using the same name for the keyword arguments and the record fields, the risk of typos is limited to the conversion function (`arg` here), which is presumably much simpler than your real `main` function.  In a large project, the conversion function could easily be generated automatically using a ppx.

Comment: I like this answer, easy to generalise and the boilerplate is quite easy to write with an emacs macro.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done quite directly if you write the field update functions for the record type.  For instance, if we have

```
type arg = { a:bool; b:bool; c:bool; d:bool; e: bool }

let main {a;b;c;d;e} = Format.eprintf "%B %B %B %B %B@." a b c d e

module Update = struct
  let a a r = { r with a }
  let b b r = { r with b }
  let c c r = { r with c }
  let d d r = { r with d }
  let e e r = { r with e }
end
```

The only missing step is to transform `Cmdliner.Term.t` that directly provides the argument into terms that update a record of type arg. An implementation would be:

```
let cmd =
  let open Cmdliner in
  (* first the starting record *)
  let start = Term.const { a = false; b=false; c=false; d=false; e=false } in
  let transform r (update,arg) = 
    Term.( const update $ arg $ r ) in
  let arg =
    List.fold_left transform
      start
      Update.[
        a, Arg.(value & flag & info ["a"] ~doc:"a");
        b, Arg.(value & flag & info ["b"] ~doc:"b");
        c, Arg.(value & flag & info ["c"] ~doc:"c");
        d, Arg.(value & flag & info ["d"] ~doc:"d");
        e, Arg.(value & flag & info ["e"] ~doc:"e");
    ] in
  Term.(const main $ arg),
  Term.info "test"
     ~version:"1"
     ~doc:"abcde"
     ~exits:Term.default_exits
     ~man:[]

let () = Cmdliner.Term.(exit @@ eval cmd)
```

Comment: I really like your solution but the problem is it makes me create a starting record which goes against the philosophy of cmdliner. That's why I don't find a solution for my problem because I'd like to find a way to go from a record of `'a Cmdliner.Term.t` to a record of `'a`.